# how to handle JSON request contains special parameters , e.g {"@type": "bill"}

Tags: python-3.x, grpc

##### special parameters handling in gRPC python

Open API's request json body contains some special key value pair. some parameters names prepended with @ symbole before the  parameter. How to handle this type of parameter in **gRPC message**? Below are given a josn request Example:

`"channel": [ { "id": "string", "href": "string", "name": "string", "role": "string", "@baseType": "string", "@schemaLocation": "string", "@type": "string", "@referredType": "string" } ],your text`

I have tried with different types of fields, like Struct, Any. But that's breaks the structure of message. you can in the below screenshot Struct type keeps the requested data in another layer. this keeps every key:value pair into another fields key.
[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear including your intent. You're correctly showing how to represent arbitrary (!) JSON objects in a Protobuf field using the WKT [`Struct`](https://protobuf.dev/reference/protobuf/google.protobuf/#struct) type.  OpenAPI represents REST APIs not gRPC APIs. If your intent is to represent this specific JSON schema using gRPC then you will need to define an equivalent message. I'm unfamiliar with tools that may help automate this process but a Google search returned [`openapi2proto`](https://github.com/nytimes/openapi2proto) (from a trustworthy source).

Comment: I suspect you're trying to use [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/industries/communications/billing-revenue/12.0/brm-rest-api/op-payment-id-get.html) Oracle API. I'm unfamiliar with it, but it appears to use `@` prefixes to represent metadata. So `@type` corresponds to some set of possible messages types. In your gRPC conversion, you would **not** include `@type` in the corresponding gRPC message because the gRPC message **is** the type.

Comment: @DazWilkin Your assumption is right. I am trying to build OpenAPI REST specification in gRPC. I implement some API specifications in RESTful way with Django, and FastAPI. Now I am trying to develop this exact specification with the gRPC protocol.

Comment: One thing to check is whether Oracle exposes its services via gRPC already (in addition to JSON/REST). Google's somewhat biased as it created gRPC but, it publishes many of its APIs as gRPC directly and so, as a developer, you've the choice. If Oracle doesn't offer gRPC, then I think you're wanting to wrap the existing JSON/REST API as a gRPC service. See whether that openapi2proto tool helps but, one thing to consider is that you'd likely benefit from an idiomatic rather than literal mapping. Because gRPC is strongly-typed, you don't need to replicate e.g. `@type` REST fields as gRPC fields